# How to write double quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this javscript code for creating a xml. Wondering where from a backslash appears  when the resulting string is loaded in xml editor or the browser

```
var i = 0;
var id = 'polyStyID_'+ i;
var kmlStyle =   '<Style id="'+ id +'">';
```

`alert(kmlStyle)` gives:`<Style id="polyStyID_0">`, which is what I want.

But the same string in the browser or xml editor shows a backslash as below

`<Style id=\"polyStyID_0\">`

What can i do in the Javascript code so that backslash does not appear in the browser?

Thanks for help.
BS

Comment: Might have something to do with the method you use to place something. Are you using a `.innerHtml()` method? It could be escaping by JS self, I know jwuery has a special `.html()` method instead of hte `. text()` method

Answer (score 1):

`\`**It is the escape character in JS**.  Hence it is shown.

Also you should consider using [**`.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

> But the same string in the browser or xml editor shows a backslash

You have the string you want.  Some places that string gets previewed may insert backslashes.  This is because it's trying to tell that those quotes do not actually terminate the string, and are instead content.

The reason `alert` works like you expect is because alter doesn't show a representation of the string, it shows the string data, which is correct.

Don't worry about the backslashes, they aren't really there. If you write the string out somewhere the backslashes will not be there, as the alert shows.

[More proof here, showing you can write this string to the the value of a form field without backslashes.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bs4gY/)